# Primefaces datatable losing data

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, lazy-loading

I'm having the following issue with a dataTable using PrimeFaces 3.4.1 and JSF 2.1.6. First time the page loads, the dataTable is filled with data from our database, but whenever an action is executed on the page (edit link, dataTable sort or filtering), the dataTable loses its data. DataTable has elements from this class:

```
package es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.sujeto.data.EnvioDataContactoEconomico;
import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.sujeto.data.EnvioDataEmpresaFilial;
import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.sujeto.data.EnvioDataHistoricoTipoSujeto;
import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.sujeto.data.EnvioDataPersonaContacto;
import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.sujeto.data.EnvioDataPlantaProduccion;
import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.sujeto.data.EnvioDataRepresentante;
import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.sujeto.data.EnvioDataSujeto;
import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.solicitudes.SolicitudSujeto;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class EnvioSujeto extends Envio implements Serializable{

@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private SolicitudSujeto solicitud;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "envioSujeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private EnvioDataContactoEconomico envioDataContactoEconomico;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "envioSujeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EnvioDataEmpresaFilial> enviosDataEmpresaFilial;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "envioSujeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EnvioDataHistoricoTipoSujeto> enviosDataHistoricoTipoSujeto;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "envioSujeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EnvioDataPlantaProduccion> enviosDataPlantaProduccion;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "envioSujeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private EnvioDataSujeto envioDataSujeto;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "envioSujeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EnvioDataPersonaContacto> enviosDataPersonaContacto;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "envioSujeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EnvioDataRepresentante> enviosDataRepresentante;

public SolicitudSujeto getSolicitud() {
    return solicitud;
}

public void setSolicitud(final SolicitudSujeto solicitud) {
    this.solicitud = solicitud;
}

... //rest of getters and setters
}
```

When debugging after an action is taken on the dataTable, we keep data only on the envioDatasujeto field, every other data on the element is lost.

Here's the xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:blb="http://ecb.bilbomatica.es/components">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:loadBundle basename="es.cne.sicbios.gestionsujetos" var="gestionmsg" />
        <h:form id="formulario">
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                closable="true" />

                <p:dataTable var="envioSujeto"
                value="#{listadoEnviosSujetoMB.lazyListaAllEnvios}" 
                paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"               
                selectionMode="single"  
                selection="#{listadoEnviosSujetoMB.envioSeleccionado}" 
                id="listaEnviosSujetos" 
                lazy="true">

                <f:facet name="header">  
                    #{gestionmsg.txt_listadoEnviosSujetos} 
                </f:facet>

                <p:column sortBy="#{envioSujeto.envioDataSujeto.datosSujeto.acronimo}" headerText="#{gestionmsg.column_acronimo}"
                    filterBy="#{envioSujeto.envioDataSujeto.datosSujeto.acronimo}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{envioSujeto.envioDataSujeto.datosSujeto.acronimo}" />                    
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{envioSujeto.solicitud.id}"
                    headerText="#{gestionmsg.column_id_tramite}"
                    filterBy="#{envioSujeto.solicitud.id}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{envioSujeto.solicitud.id}" />                    
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{envioSujeto.fechaCreacion.time}"
                    headerText="#{gestionmsg.column_fechaCreacion}"
                    filterBy="#{envioSujeto.fechaCreacion.time}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{envioSujeto.fechaCreacion.time}" >
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{envioSujeto.tipo}"
                    headerText="#{gestionmsg.column_tipoEnvio}"
                    filterBy="#{envioSujeto.tipo}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{envioSujeto.tipo}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{envioSujeto.solicitud.estado}"
                    headerText="#{gestionmsg.column_estado}"
                    filterBy="#{envioSujeto.solicitud.estado}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{envioSujeto.solicitud.estado}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{envioSujeto.idRegistro}"
                    headerText="#{gestionmsg.column_idRegistro}"
                    filterBy="#{envioSujeto.idRegistro}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{envioSujeto.idRegistro}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column sortBy="#{envioSujeto.id}"
                    headerText="id"
                    filterBy="#{envioSujeto.id}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{envioSujeto.id}" />
                </p:column>
                <ui:remove>
                <!-- 
                <p:column 
                    headerText="#{gestionmsg.column_bloqueo}"
                    >
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </p:column>
                 -->
                 </ui:remove>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:commandLink icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                update=":formulario"
                actionListener="#{listadoEnviosSujetoMB.goToEditarEnvio}"  >    
                <h:outputText value="Editar" />                                         
            </p:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And the managed bean for it:

```
package es.cne.sicbios.managedbean.gestionsujetos;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.Envio;
import es.cne.sicbios.services.tramites.envios.IEnvioService;
import es.cne.sicbios.utils.FacesUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "listadoEnviosSujetoMB")
public class ListadoEnviosSujetoMB implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{envioSujetoService}")
private IEnvioService envioService;
private Envio envio;
private List<Envio> listaAllEnvios;
private LazyEnvioSujetoDataModel lazyListaAllEnvios;
private Envio envioSeleccionado;

/**
 * 
 * Getters y Setters
 */
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    if (lazyListaAllEnvios == null) {
        lazyListaAllEnvios = new LazyEnvioSujetoDataModel(envioService);
    }
}

public void setEnvioService(final IEnvioService envioService) {
    this.envioService = envioService;
}

public Envio getEnvio() {
    return envio;
}

public void setEnvio(final Envio envio) {
    this.envio = envio;
}

public List<Envio> getListaAllEnvios() {
    if (listaAllEnvios == null) {
        listaAllEnvios =  envioService.getAll();
    }
    return listaAllEnvios;
}

public void setListaAllEnvios(final List<Envio> listaAllEnvios) {
    this.listaAllEnvios = listaAllEnvios;
}

public Envio getEnvioSeleccionado() {
    return envioSeleccionado;
}

public void setEnvioSeleccionado(final Envio envioSeleccionado) {
    this.envioSeleccionado = envioSeleccionado;
}

/**
 * Métodos de navegación
 */
public String goToEditarEnvio() {
    FacesUtils.saveObjectInFlashScope("envio", envioSeleccionado);
    return "/pages/gestionsujetos/envio.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}

public LazyEnvioSujetoDataModel getLazyListaAllEnvios() {
    return lazyListaAllEnvios;
}

public void setLazyListaAllEnvios(final LazyEnvioSujetoDataModel lazyListaAllEnvios) {
    this.lazyListaAllEnvios = lazyListaAllEnvios;
}
}
```

Also, we tried to do a lazy load of the data, but it doesn't work. This is the data model we used (an adapted class from the Lazy Loading example on PrimeFaces.org):

```
package es.cne.sicbios.managedbean.gestionsujetos;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

import es.cne.sicbios.entities.tramites.envios.Envio;
import es.cne.sicbios.services.tramites.envios.IEnvioService;

/**
 * Dummy implementation of LazyDataModel that uses a list to mimic a real datasource like a database.
 */
@ViewScoped
public class LazyEnvioSujetoDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Envio> implements Serializable, SelectableDataModel<Envio> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 983251078912322527L;
private final List<Envio> datasource;


public List<Envio> getDatasource() {
    return datasource;
}

public LazyEnvioSujetoDataModel(final IEnvioService envioService) {
    this.datasource = envioService.getAll();
}

@Override
public Envio getRowData(final String rowKey) {
    for(final Envio envio : datasource) {
        if(envio.getId().equals(rowKey))
            return envio;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(final Envio envio) {
    return envio.getId();
}

@Override
public List<Envio> load(final int first, final int pageSize,
        final String sortField, final SortOrder sortOrder, final Map<String,String> filters) {
    final List<Envio> data = new ArrayList<Envio>();

    //filter
    for(final Envio envio : datasource) {
        boolean match = true;

        for(final Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            try {
                final String filterProperty = it.next();
                final String filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);
                final String fieldValue = String.valueOf(envio.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(envio));

                if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue)) {
                    match = true;
                }
                else {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            } catch(final Exception e) {
                match = false;
            }
        }

        if(match) {
            data.add(envio);
        }
    }

    //sort
    //      if(sortField != null) {
    //          Collections.sort(data, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));
    //      }

    //rowCount
    final int dataSize = data.size();
    this.setRowCount(dataSize);

    //paginate
    if(dataSize > pageSize) {
        try {
            return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
        }
        catch(final IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
        }
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
}
}
```

Any idea for this problem?
Thanks in advance,
Juanjo.

Comment: If your beans are `@ViewScoped` make sure you action are `void` or return `null`

Comment: I changed the goToEditarEnvio so it only saves the object on the flash, and returns null. On the commandLink, I added the following:   
actionListener="#{listadoEnviosSujetoMB.goToEditarEnvio}"  
      action="/pages/gestionsujetos/envio.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"  . However, the problem persists.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve , but If you redirect, how do you are getting a new view...

Comment: I'm trying to navigate to an edit page for the selected item from the list, so yes, I need to get another view. The "redirect=true" is wrong, you're right, and I changed it, but unfortunally that's not the problem. Problem is, when I realize any action before navigate (even clicking the edit link for navigate to the new page), the data on the dataTable is lost, so the element I stored on the flash, to edit on the next view, is lost for some reason before reaching that new view. By example, after loading, if I change the pagination and debug the data on the bean, the list already is lost.

Comment: you may consider opening the edit in a dialog without navigating away...

Comment: That would be ideal. Sadly, the bean contains a lot of data for a dialog (its page contains four tabs with several fields each), and, most important, web application is a new version from an existing web application, and client wants to keep aesthetically as seemed as possible. It's a handicap, I know. In the old application, the edit list leads to the edit page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend of the teamwork get the answer for this issue. We're using the Spring Tool Suite, and sometimes it was changing the saving method for JSF's managed beans. We need to have this on our web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it after I realized it was because I was accidentally using

```
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
```

package in stead of

```
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
```